# Kaggle R Notebook not showing the plots images

Tags: r, kaggle

I am trying to pass the RMarkdown I have made in Rstudio to a Notebook in Kaggle, once finished the draft showing all the graphics... when publishing it does not show any of the images, I have edited it again adding a variable to try to print and save the image like:

```
a <- ggplot(data = daily_activity) +.
   geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=month)) +
   labs(x = "month", y = "Total activity", title = "Monthly activity distribution")

print(a)

ggsave("output.png", plot = a)
```

but nothing changes, any idea to solve this problem would be of great help.

It shows an error loading the "hms" package